# MVVMCROSS Android Release built checkbox & switch binding not work

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, linker, mvvmcross

I am having an issue with binding checkbox & switch in Xamarin Android with Mvvmcross 5.6.3, target api 26. Both widgets are used in fragment in appcomp activity. It works with linking “sdk assemblies only” but not “sdk and user assemblies”.
Bindings in xml are very simple:

```
  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:text=""
      local:MvxBind="Checked Selected"
      local:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mvxCachedImageView_lock"
      local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        style="@style/EntryHeaderStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxLang="Text LabelShowStatusMarker"
        local:MvxBind="Checked SettingMasterViewModel.AppSetting.IsShowingStatusMarker" />
```

I have the standard LinerPleaseInclude with additional properties set as follow:

```
    public void Include(CheckBox checkBox)
    {
        checkBox.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
        checkBox.Checked = true;
        checkBox.Enabled = true;
        checkBox.Clickable = true;
    }

    public void Include(Switch @switch)
    {
        @switch.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => @switch.Checked = !@switch.Checked;
        @switch.Checked = true;
        @switch.Enabled = true;
        @switch.Clickable = true;
    }
    public void Include(CompoundButton cb)
    {
        cb.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
    }
```

Though it should not be necessary, I replicate the above code for the appcomp v7 checkbox & switch widgets already. Nothing helps.
There is no message in android log for this kind of issue. No clue of what else is required but stripped out during linking.  Please help.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT It was solved. Thanks